# R - Plotting mesh with lattice wireframe

Tags: r, plot, mesh, lattice

I'm trying to plot a mesh over some points in 3D to make some kind of landscape. But, actually I have some problems with the lattice wireframe function. The function doesn't show all the vertices. I'm anyway not sure, if the wireframe function is the best way to do this? Basically I'm looking for a function that maps the ListPlot3D function of Mathematica.

```
library(lattice)

col1 <- c(1.02,1.00,1.02,1.01,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.01,1.00,0.99,1.01,0.98,0.99)
col2 <- c(1.00,0.99,1.00,1.01,0.98,0.99,1.00,1.01,1.02,0.99,1.00,1.01,1.00)
col3 <- c(0.98,0.99,0.99,0.99,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.01,1.01,1.01,1.02)

data <- data.frame(phen=col1,param1=col2,param2=col3)

wireframe(phen ~ param1 * param2,
          data=data,
          xlab="param1", 
          ylab="param2", 
          zlab="phen",shade = T,
          aspect = c(1, 0.2), 
          scales=list(arrows=FALSE))
```

My plot then misses following data points:

```
p1 <- c(1.02,1.00,0.98)
p2 <- c(1.00,0.98,1.00)
p3 <- c(1.00,1.02,1.00)
p4 <- c(0.99,1.00,1.02)
```

These are points from the data frame that get not plotted by the wireframe function. It is not clear to me, why they are not included.

[wireframe plot with missing points: The red dots are marking data that is actually existing in the data frame, BUT not in the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLQFZ.jpg)

I'm totally running out of ideas what's going on here?

Thanks for any advice on that!

EDIT: added plot

Comment: Not clear what you were expecting. If you want to see points then you need to use the `cloud` function. If you want to mix them, then you need to use panel functions.

Comment: I actually don't want to see points. I want to have all the data from the data frame included into the plot.

Comment: I think the problem is that there are no other points on the same x or y values on the  "grid" for those points. From the wireframe help page: `In the case of wireframe, calculations are based on the assumption that the x and y values are evaluated on a rectangular grid defined by their unique values.` Let me see if I can cobble a work-around. Sorry, Even putting NA values along one of the grid line to attempt getting "triangles" back to the "main body" failed for me: `data2 <-rbind(data, data.frame(phen=c(NA, 1, NA), param1=c( 1, 1, 1) , param2= c(1.02, 1,  .98) ) )`